# Como usar variável em mais de um controller no AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

Estou precisando usar uma variável, no angular, que eu possa usar em mais de um controller. Sim os controllers estão no mesmo arquivo.
Como posso fazer isso?

```
.controller('denResCtrl', function($scope, $window, $http) {

$scope.fazerDenuncia = function (denuncia) {

    var diaDenun = formatarData(denuncia.dataDenun);
    var hora = denuncia.horaDenun;
    var tipo = denuncia.tipoDenun;
    var des = denuncia.descricao;

    var end = $window.localStorage.getItem('logradouro');
    var numeroEnd = denuncia.numeroEndereco;
    var cid = $window.localStorage.getItem('cidade');
    var estado = $window.localStorage.getItem('estado');

$http.get('http://localhost:8888/sistemas/webApps/ionic/vcApp/www/php/getCordenates.php?end='+end+'&numeroEnd='+numeroEnd+'&cid='+cid+'&estado='+estado).success(function (data) {
        var coordenadas = data;

    })

  }

})
```

As variáveis que estão no controller atual, eu criei nela mesma, e não existiam.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [$rootScope](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$rootScope).

```
.controller('denResCtrl', function($scope, $window, $http, $rootScope) {
    $rootScope.forAnotherCtrl = 'some value';
})

.controller('AnotherCtrl', function($rootScope) {
    console.log($rootScope.forAnotherCtrl);
})
```

Comment: Bá! $rootScope é muito barbada pelo que vejo.
E Marco, isso que o Geferson colocou de colocar no arquivo app.js um .run e tal, serviria caso eu queira declara uma variável global pro projeto todo, é isso? Ou da forma que vc fez, também serve?

Comment: Também serve. Ele fica disponível no em todo o seu projeto, porém somente após esta variável for definida. Entretanto, usando ela no método run() ou da forma mencionada pelo Geferson, a variável é definida no momento em que a aplicação é inicializada.

Comment: Certo, Marcos, entendi.
Voltando a sua resposta, então, todas as variáveis que eu criei, nesse controller, eu tenho que tirar o var e colocar $rootScope.variavelCriada, certo?

Comment: Se vc deseja que fiquem disponíveis em outro controller, sim, isso mesmo!

Comment: Complementando, só não esquece de injetar a dependência de $rootScope no controller, se não aposto que vai dar erro rsrsrs

Answer (score 5):

Você tem duas opções pra isso: $rootScope ou um Service.

Caso queira fazer uma variável global para usar em todos os controllers pode usar o $rootScope, que é o escopo compartilhando entre os controllers.

Um exemplo simples seria criar no App.js no método run() uma variável:

Obs: Criei nesse método, pois ele executa ao abrir a aplicação, mas você pode colocar uma variável em $rootScope em qualquer controller.

App.js

**$rootScope**

```
.run(['$rootScope',
function ($rootScope) {

   $rootScope.variavelGlobal = "Teste";

}]);
```

Para acessar no controller basta fazer isso:

```
angular.module('MeuModulo')
    .controller('MeuController',
            ['$scope', '$rootScope',
                function ($scope, $rootScope) {

             console.log($rootScope.variavelglobal);

         //Isso pode ser feito também
         $rootScope.outraVariavelGlobal = "Teste2";                  
     }]);
```

Outra solucão seria Criar um **Service** pra isso

```
angular.module('MeuModulo')
    .factory('MeuService', [function () {
            var aux = "";
            return {
                getMinhaVariavelGlobal: function () {
                    //Faz Alguma coisa aqui, busca de Um webservice, localStorage, etc..
                    aux = "Teste3";
                    return aux;
                }
            }
        }]);
```

E para pegar o valor no controller, basta injetar o service e chamar a função getMinhaVariavelGlobal()

```
angular.module('MeuModulo')
    .controller('MeuController', function ($scope, MeuService) {
        var aux2 = MeuService.getMinhaVariavelGlobal();
        console.log(aux2);
    })
```